# how to add multiple default routes ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: routing, linux-networking, ubuntu-16.04, route, iproute2

I have the following commands and outputs
Here are my current commands (this work fine on RHEL system **but not on ubuntu**)

```
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth0 tab 1
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth1 tab 2
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth2 tab 3
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth3 tab 4
ip route add default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth4 tab 5
ip rule add from 10.1.1.13/32 tab 1 priority 500
ip rule add from 10.1.1.31/32 tab 2 priority 600
ip rule add from 10.1.1.35/32 tab 3 priority 700
ip rule add from 10.1.1.36/32 tab 4 priority 800
ip rule add from 10.1.1.39/32 tab 5 priority 900
```

and here are the results of these commands(which is not doing exactly what i want)

> ip route show

```
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth0
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.13
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.31
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.35
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.36
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.39
```

> ip rule show

```
0:  from all lookup local
500:    from 10.1.1.13 lookup 1
600:    from 10.1.1.31 lookup 2
700:    from 10.1.1.35 lookup 3
800:    from 10.1.1.36 lookup 4
900:    from 10.1.1.39 lookup 5
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

> route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth2
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth4
```

### BUT here is what i want it to be

> ip route show

```
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth0
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth1
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth2
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth3
default via 10.1.1.1 dev eth4
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.13
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.31
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.35
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.36
10.1.1.0/24 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.39
```

> ip rule show

```
0:  from all lookup local
500:    from 10.1.1.13 lookup 1
600:    from 10.1.1.31 lookup 2
700:    from 10.1.1.35 lookup 3
800:    from 10.1.1.36 lookup 4
900:    from 10.1.1.39 lookup 5
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

> route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth3
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth4
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth2
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3
10.1.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth4
```

So what command on **UBUNTU 16.04 LTS** can i run that will make me add more default routes?

**NOTE:** Again this is called asymmetrical routing on linux and here are people that have it work or need this time of routing as well

## 1 https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2135343

## 2 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=404398

## 3 http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7291?page=0,0

Comment: There can only be one default route. Hence the name "default".

Comment: not true this works in RHEL very well and multiple default routes
also check this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2135343&p=12603718#post12603718

Comment: i have done this on RHEL 7 and works perfect and the output am looking for is what i have seen work on RHEL 7 which ubuntu has refused to allow to work..this is called **asymmetrical routing**